# How to show structure windows in TeXnicCenter?

Tags: texniccenter

[TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/) should be able to show window with structure of document:

[image]

I clicked through all menu but I am not able to find this option somewhere. I use last version (2.0 Beta 1) from their website.

Comment: You can press `CTRL+Alt+O` to show the structure. I think this only works for projects, not individual files that are not part of a project. To start a project look under the corresponding menu entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a *project* in order to have a visible "structure." Moreover, this terminology has been updated and is now referred to as an "outline." And, with each project, there is an associated "main file." It's *this* file that TeXnicCenter starts with in order to build the outline view. To show the TeXnicCenter outline of a project, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (or via the menus View > Tool Windows > Outline).

Note that the outline displayed requires a specific format for your files. That is, TeXnicCenter parses the main project file with every "Save" operation (*but not if it autosaves before you compile!*), including any subsidiary (included files). For example, if you have a project that has a main file `latex_stuff.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
\include{myinput}
\end{document}
```

together with `myinput.tex`:

```
\section{section 2}
\begin{figure}\caption{Figure caption}\label{figure}\end{figure}
\begin{table}\caption{Table caption}\end{table}
\subsection{subsection 1}
```

it will render in the project outline as

[image]

See how the project only displays the caption of the labelled float (`figure`), while the `table` is left blank. Moreover, if you define your own environments or macros with names other than the default ones, they won't be picked up by TeXnicCenter.